# Grid and Vertical list with one RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I want to use Grid and Linear layout in one recycle view. Is it possible to use 2 layout manager in on RecyclerView. 
If not then please tell me the best way to do this. 
[image: I want some thing like that.]

Answer (score 0):

You will take 2 RecyclerView for this.

2 `LayoutManager` because one is grid (GridLayoutManager) and other is linear(LinearLayoutManager),

2 `adapters` because your `item views` are different.